# recvfrom() is stuck and I don't know why

Tags: c, winsock2

I have a project to do for my school. The goal is to create a ping like program that use echo service (C programming). The echo service normally runs on UDP port 7 and have to be activated with the Simple TCP/IP. Echo is supposed to reply a message if it gets one.
Here is the code I made:

```
// ping.cpp : entry point

#include "ping.h"
#pragma comment(lib,"WS2_32") //Library


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    //Variable
    char IPAdress[] = "127.0.0.1";
    WORD versionProtocoleSocket;
    SOCKET pingSocket;
    struct sockaddr_in destination;
    char packet[MAX_PACKET_SIZE], reply[MAX_PACKET_SIZE];
    int err, msgLength;

    //Initialisation of Windows Socket
    printf("Initialising WSA 2.2...\n");
    versionProtocoleSocket = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    err = initialiseSocket(versionProtocoleSocket);
    if (err != 0) {
        errSocket(err);
        printf("The program will stop\n");
        _getch();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else
        printf("Initialisation success\n\n");

    //Socket creation
    printf("Socket creation...\n");
    if ((pingSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Can't create socket\nThe program is going to stop\n");
        _getch();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else
        printf("Creation sucess\n\n");

    //Préparation des variables pour l'utilisation de la fonction sendto()
    destination.sin_family = AF_INET;
    destination.sin_port = htons(7);
    destination.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(adresseIP);
    msgLength = sizeof(message);
    int addrSize = sizeof(destination);

    //Beginning of ping
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        //Sending
        if (sendto(pingSocket, message, messageLength, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&destination, addrSize) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            printf("Can't send message : %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        else
            printf("Message %d sent\n", i);
        //Reception
        if (recvfrom(pingSocket, reply, MAX_PACKET_SIZE, 0, NULL, NULL) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            printf("Error : %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        else
            printf("Message %d received\n", i);
    }


    _getch();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int initialiserSocket(WORD version) {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int err = WSAStartup(version, &wsaData);
    return err;
}

void errSocket(int err) {
    switch (err) {
    case WSASYSNOTREADY:
        printf("System is not ready\n");
        break;
    case WSAVERNOTSUPPORTED:
        printf("Unsuported protocol version\n");
        break;
    case WSAEINPROGRESS:
        printf("A version is already running\n");
        break;
    case WSAEPROCLIM:
        printf("Max task reached\n");
        break;
    case WSAEFAULT:
        printf("pointer lpWSAData is not valid\n");
        break;
    default:
        printf("Unknown error\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

Now the ping.h code :

```
#pragma once
#include "stdio.h"
#include "winsock2.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "stdint.h"

int initialiseSocket(WORD version);
void errSocket(int err);

#define MAX_PACKET_SIZE 10*1024
```

The problem is that my program is stuck on the recvfrom function and I have no idea why.
Can you explain?

Comment: You mix up a few things... "PING like" is not the same as a UDP echo server. Ping uses ICMP echo request, not UDP. Also UDP is not TCP/IP.

Answer (score 2):

You have no socket listening for packets. You need to [bind](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/listen_for_and_receive_udp_datagrams_in_c.html#idp42704) your receiving socket to the address and port you want to use.

Also note that UDP does not guarantee delivery. If nothing is listening for your packet, it will just get thrown away. So you need to be listening **before** you send the packet. Obviously, that presents a problem in a single thread. Typically, you would have two separate processes (either different programs or created by forking). One process would create a socket and listen on the port and the other would create a socket and send the data.

Comment: No, this is no problem in a single thread. If the socket is bound, a received packet will be buffered until a call to recvfrom(). It is _not_ necessary, that the process currently hangs in recvfrom() to receive a udp packet.

Comment: `sendto()` performs an implicit bind if it is called on an unbound socket.

Comment: @Ctx the *receive* socket is not bound.

Comment: @JeremyP There is only one socket, `pingSocket` and it is bound after the call to `sendto()`. My point was, that you do not need to be stuck in `recvfrom()` at the moment when the packet arrives, it will be buffered until `recvfrom()` is called.

Comment: And yet the packet has gone. This is UDP. There's no requirement for anybody to buffer anything anywhere.

Comment: @JeremyP Well, if you put it this way it would be perfectly valid for an OS to drop all incoming UDP packets altogether. And outgoing one's, too. It's UDP, correct? Nobody may expect to receive it. But seriously: Buffering is how sane OS behave, precisely to eliminate the need to have a process/thread permanently lingering in `recvfrom()`

Comment: There's no guarantee of delivery of UDP packets. It is perfectly valid to drop them all. I think, in this case, there is a race condition arising because he is sending and receiving on the same socket.

Comment: @JeremyP Yet UDP works; this is because most OS primarily tend to implement things to be useful, not only to be strictly conforming (e.g. by discarding all UDP packets). Surprisingly this also holds true for Windows in this case. So, there _is_ a listening socket for the packets (pingSocket after being bound by `sendto`) and there is _no_ need for a separate listening thread. I'm sorry, but both points of your answer are not applicable here and there's no room for a race condition, too... The problem remains unclear, perhaps the server does not reply for some reason...